# Use regex, php or regex in conjunction with php to detect the presence of a trailing slash at the end of the URL?

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm trying to use `preg_match` in conjunction with regex to detect whether there is a trailing slash at the end of a URL.

If there is a trailing slash at the end of the URL, I'd like to use PHP to delete the trailing slash from the URL.

Comment: so you are basically just trying to check the last character in the string?

Answer (score 3):

The most appropriate function for this case is [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
```

This will actually remove *all* trailing slashes (and not a maximum of one), but I doubt this is something to be concerned about when talking URLs.

There is no need to use a regex or other heavy-duty tools.

Comment: Probably the best tool for that job. clever. +1

Comment: In my case, I do actually require the tool to delete JUST the trailing slash at the end of the URL, not all the slashes because the URL from the user inputted data will likely have more than one trailing slash and the only slash that needs to be trimmed is the slash at the end, not any of the slashes prior. Is there a way to regex preg_match and then rtrim the slash in the string that matches?

Comment: @Daphne: *Trailing* slash === slash at the end. This will not remove any slashes in the middle of the URL, as the description of `rtrim` clearly states. But it will remove both trailing slashes from e.g. `http://server/path//`.

Comment: Right, sorry. I misunderstood the purpose of rtrim. This solution works perfectly then.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(.*)\/$/
```

This should evaluate to true if trailing slah, false otherwise.

Regex group 1 is the URL without the trailing slash.